# Does REM make sense on border-radius?

Tags: css

I'm using REM units for my project. I would like to use a uniform type of units for all the project. I'm working with a group of developers and I'm trying to find a reason why I would have to apply REM units in all the CSS rules, but sometimes I maybe find it excessive or completely useless.

I would like to know if the following is necessary, benefits or disadvantages:

```
input{
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 2rem 0;
    min-width: 12rem;
    height: 4rem;
    padding: 0 2rem;
    width: 100%;
}
```

In this example you can see the border-radius is 5px as the HTML has applied `font-size: 62.5%` to have an easier method applying the REM units.

Comment: Maybe you should think of a fall back in px or em for older browser too. If you use a preprocessor like sass , you may set a  value for font-size in a var, and set it then in html and anywhere it should be a rem unit

Comment: @GCyrillus The older browser issue is something different. I'm asking what are the advantages and disadvantages of using rem in border-radius, if they even exist

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/theres-more-to-the-css-rem-unit-than-font-sizing/ Might be helpful to read.

Comment: Why use both padding and height on an input? Height is already set if you set font size and vertical padding isn't it? No need for height property

Comment: Depends on the design you want for huge rounded blocks vs. small ones. See Twitter Bootstrap which uses 3 different values for border-radius (or more). Huge blocks have huge rounding, not a 4px one. If you want 4-8px everywhere for example well go for it. If you want a fixed value, then use `px` unit. It depends©

Comment: I thought it might make a difference when zooming in, but it does not https://codepen.io/fabswt/pen/vYBZJRE

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no technical reason not to use the `rem` unit for `border-radius`. Neither is never any compelling reason to use the `rem` unit, for it or otherwise. Using `rem` is merely something chosen for convenience, as it may help to avoid computing multipliers for the `em` unit, at the cost of reduced cross-browser functionality.

It is generally safest to use the same unit for different dimensions, and this applies to `border-radius`, too, when the height and width of the element have been set in `rem` units. The reason is that this ensures that the shape is preserved if the font size of the root element is changed. If you set the `border-radius` e.g. in `px` units and width and height in `rem` units and the font size of the root element is then set to, say, 32pt, the element box becomes rather large but the border curvature remains small.